# What is the difference between node.removeChild and (c)=>node.removeChild(c)?

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote this simple code to remove all text inside of a h2 element:

```
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
const children = Array.from(h2.childNodes)
                      .filter((childNode)=>childNode.nodeName === '#text');
children.forEach(h2.removeChild); // Throws TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

However, the last line threw an error - TypeError: Illegal invocation. This was fixed when I replaced the last line with:

```
children.forEach((child)=>h2.removeChild(child)); // Just works
```

My question is, why did javascript throw the error in the first place and why did the arrow function fix it? h2.removeChild is a function that takes 1 argument, so shouldn't ( h2.removeChild ) act identically to ( (child)=>h2.removeChild(child) ) ?

Comment: @Quentin  console.log.call(null, [array]); does not give me a type error in google chrome.

Comment: Even if the function the duplicate is asking about no longer suffers from the problem, it is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are losing the correct context of `.removeChild` function here.
You could also do this:

```
children.forEach(h2.removeChild.bind(h2));
```

Comment: Ok, just tried it, just curious, why is 'this' undefined in a forEach?

Comment: It is not `undefined`, it is `window`.

Comment: @Bsalex — Only if you've failed to enable strict mode.

Comment: @Quentin, Yes, you are right. Good point.

Comment: Why does (child)=>h2.removeChild(child)  save the context? It is defined in the same lexical location, so why does making it an arrow function change the context of the function call?

Comment: @keithlee96 — The value of `this` for non-arrow functions depends on how they are called. Passing `h2.removeChild` as an argument does so without passing the context of `h2`

Comment: @Quentin Hmm, thanks. Is there somewhere I can find the documentation that says that node.removeChild must be called with it's 'this' value bound to itself?

Comment: [mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) "node is the parent node of child"

Comment: Last question, why does the Array.prototype.forEach() function bind the value of 'this' in the callback function to the (Window object / undefined)?